# C# WPF Ping Exception

Tags: c#

I have this code working as is but no matter what I try, if you enter an invalid address I get a PingException and the program crashes.  What is the best way to capture the exception and just update the textblock to "Device not found"?

```
private void actionPing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ping myPing = new Ping();

        PingReply reply = myPing.Send(HostNameTyped.Text.ToString(), 1000);
        if (reply != null)
        {
           string tripTime = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();
            if (tripTime == "0")
            {
                PingStatus1.Text = "Device not found";
            }
            else
            {
                PingStatus1.Text = "Ping Successful, " + reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms roundtrip";
            }
        }
```

Comment: A `try-catch-block` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

```cs
            try
            {
                Ping myPing = new Ping();

                PingReply reply = myPing.Send(HostNameTyped.Text.ToString(), 1000);
                if (reply != null)
                {
                    string tripTime = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();
                    if (tripTime == "0")
                    {
                        PingStatus1.Text = "Device not found";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PingStatus1.Text = "Ping Successful, " + reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms roundtrip";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                PingStatus1.Text = "Device not found";
            }
```

Comment: Thank you!  Still learning :-) Stupid easy now that I see what you did.

Comment: @Shawn Don't forget it's [good practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-specific-exceptions-in-a-catch-block) to catch a specific type of exception (e.g. `catch (PingException) { ... }`) so as not to mask other exceptions that you didn't expect.